# SAI - DAI Symbol Not Captured Right Web3.py

Tags: web3.py, receipts

trying to capture the symbol of the receipts of [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x52caaf79bf913064a70a6c9d917fd4190cdb099fe79e7d3a9dfe0600e1cfbc81) using web3.py. I am getting the DAI, DAI and DAI... while this should return SAI, SAI, DAI. Although, I checked that the correct SAI contract is being picked up under the logs of the transaction. Can someone tell me if this is a bug in my code or a bug with how web3.py pick up the symbol from the node?

```
import json
import urllib.request
from web3 import Web3
import web3

provider = Web3.HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
w3 = Web3(provider)
ether_scan_api ='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
tx_hash = '0x52caaf79bf913064a70a6c9d917fd4190cdb099fe79e7d3a9dfe0600e1cfbc81'
receipt=  w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
transfer_event = "Transfer(address,address,uint256)"
transfer_event_hashed = w3.keccak(text=transfer_event)
transactions = list()


def get_abi(erc_20_address):
    requrl  = 'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address='+erc_20_address+'&apikey='+ ether_scan_api
    while True:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(requrl) as url:
            if url.code != 200:
                raise NotImplementedError('I don\'t know how to handle HTTP code {} :('.format(url.code))
            else:
                result = json.loads(url.read())

                if result['status'] == '1':
                    break
    return  json.loads(result['result'])


for log in receipt.logs:
    if log["topics"][0]==transfer_event_hashed:                
        contract_address = w3.eth.web3.toChecksumAddress(log["address"])                
        token_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address ,abi=get_abi(contract_address))
        symbol = str(token_contract.functions.symbol().call()[:3])
        print(symbol)
```

[image]

Printing the receipt returns this

```
AttributeDict({'address': '0x89d24A6b4CcB1B6fAA2625fE562bDD9a23260359',
 'blockHash': HexBytes('0x9e48b35141e53758171239d618a02a9a0e073506b12a5fecca59240c0e032487'),
 'blockNumber': 9560511,
 'data': '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d529ae9e860000',
 'logIndex': 156,
 'removed': False,
 'topics': [HexBytes('0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef'),
  HexBytes('0x00000000000000000000000017b11c26f6cb263864610379a6ebec29da49aa2d'),
  HexBytes('0x000000000000000000000000c73e0383f3aff3215e6f04b0331d58cecf0ab849')],
 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0x52caaf79bf913064a70a6c9d917fd4190cdb099fe79e7d3a9dfe0600e1cfbc81'),
 'transactionIndex': 111})
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error, just the print(symbol) is returning DAI, DAI, DAI, while it should return SAI, SAI and DAI (being the receipt symbols). I am initializing the contract under w3.eth.contract with contracts hashes being read from the logs. Although this contract 0x89d24A6b4CcB1B6fAA2625fE562bDD9a23260359 is SAI, it's returning the DAI symbol for some reason.

Comment: You're calling function `symbol` on the same `token_contract`. What made you expect to get a different result every time??? This function returns a constant string, and the same constant string every time it is called.

Comment: Well maybe I misunderstood, but in the receipt, the contracts under the logs are 
0x89d24A6b4CcB1B6fAA2625fE562bDD9a23260359, 
0x89d24A6b4CcB1B6fAA2625fE562bDD9a23260359 and 
0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F
looking them up on etherscan, it shows SAI for the first two and DAI for the last one...
As I am looping on the logs in the receipt that have the hash corresponding to a 'Transfer(address,address,uint256)' event

Comment: So you should create a different `w3.eth.contract` instance for each one of them, and then call the `symbol` function on each one of these instances.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but when doing 
token_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address ,abi=get_abi(contract_address)) in the for loop, 
Doesn't this part create a new instance on each pass of the loop...

Comment: Wait, it's actually what you're doing; let me check again...

Comment: Can you please `print(contract_address)` and make sure that it is not the same one in every iteration of the loop?

Comment: yes I did before posting this... the print is in the question

Comment: Also, I believe that you should use something like `log["to"]` instead of `log["address"]`. Print the entire receipt (or at least one of the logs) and see if you can find a `to` field in there (perhaps not directly inside `log`).

Comment: I'll check it out... But question here, the address 0x89d24A6b4CcB1B6fAA2625fE562bDD9a23260359... looking it up on etherscan returns SAI, when I put it through web3.py to find the symbol I get DAI... aren't these two things supposed to be equivalent?

Comment: Etherscan takes it from the designated ERC20 token contract, which should be specified in the `to` field of the transaction receipt.

Comment: I just printed the first log in the receipt that corresponds to the event "Transfer(address,address,uint256)" and there isn't a "to" address there... It's in the question above

Comment: What about the entire receipt? Can you print that?

Comment: There is one "from" and one "to" address in the receipt, but this corresponds to contract 0xc73e0383f3aff3215e6f04b0331d58cecf0ab849 which doesn't have an underlying token designated anywhere... This contract is the one the user interacts with to have his transaction executed, I don't know if this is where the receipt tokens are picked up from... When you say the "to" field, there should be one "to" for each token transferred? Probably different coding by JS and Python

Comment: No, your code seems right. In particularly, those two contracts are indeed storing the two symbols that you're mentioning. Can you please try to `print(token_contract.functions.symbol)` and see what it given you?

Comment: doing print(token_contract.functions.symbol().call())
returns the below, which are indeed different as I can see the last contract doesn't have x00... 
b'DAI\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

b'DAI\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

DAI

Comment: Well, I meant for you to just print the function pointer itself, so we could see if you're actually calling different functions (not even sure that would work anyway). But your check is possibly even better. What exactly difference do you see? Didn't quite understand from your comment.

Comment: this `'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` is being printed for the SAI contract but not the DAI one... yeah printing the function you specified returns just "<Function symbol>" lol this is the first time I print a literal function

Comment: OK, so my answer below if 1 minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you this, but the symbol value in both contracts is DAI.

The only difference being that the "SAI" contract implements `bytes32 public symbol`, while the DAI contract implements `string public symbol`.

The ERC20 standard dictates that the latter should be used.

Unfortunately, some token vendors have failed to fully comply with the standard, in particularly at the early days of the blockchain; I guess they thought it wouldn't matter much.

Unfortunately it does. You are fetching the interface from Etherscan and then use it in order to create a contract object, but most applications assume the interface function `function symbol() public pure returns (string memory)`, and when they call it, they either get a runtime exception or incorrect data.

In any case, as you can see [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0x89d24a6b4ccb1b6faa2625fe562bdd9a23260359#readContract), the value returned by the `symbol` function in the "SAI" contract is:

```
0x4441490000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

If you convert it to ASCII, then you get:

- `0x44 == D`
- `0x41 == A`
- `0x49 == I`

Comment: Great thanks for clearing it up... these guys are not any token vendors.. weird that something like this would happen

Comment: @AceCal: I meant, token deployers or whatever you'd like to call that (not quite sure about the meaning of *vendor*, perhaps I was wrong in using it in this context).